# Angular2, Data is keep binded to the original variable inside the function also

Tags: arrays, angular, data-binding

I'm calling a function to replicate the data inside *ngFor loop like below.

```
<li (click)="replicateTicket(data);">&nbsp; Replicate</li>
```

Inside the function I'm updating name and Id of variable and pushing it inside the array. (In given example I'm not pushing the data to explain the behavior more vividly.

```
replicateTicket(data:any){
          data.name = data.name + ' (Replicated)';
          console.log(this.ticketList[this.ticketList.length-1].id);
          data.id = 0;
          console.log(this.ticketList[this.ticketList.length-1].id);
}
```

What I want is If id of original data is 5 than it should not change to 0.

1. Run [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HY8m6yuB6X5Wo1C9HlZV?p=preview)
2. click on 458 abc.
3. It should only update the new data and not the current one.

Am I doing Something wrong?

Comment: Faced the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create copy of the current object, change it and then push new object into an array, something like this for example: (I used code from your Plunker)

```
replicateTicket(ticket:any){
    let t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ticket));
    t.name += ' (Replicated)';
    t.id = 0;
    this.ticketList.push(t);
}
```

Comment: but I don't understand this behavior, Is this a bug?

Comment: @YASHDAVE It's not a bug, what you're doing in your Plunker is the following: you're referencing to same object each time and pushing it to an array over and over again and that's why all of them are changed - all elements of an array are basically one same instance of the object you created initially, but `let t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ticket));` creates copy of an object each time.

Comment: than it should work by let t = ticket also.But it doesn't. @stefan-svrkota

Comment: @YASHDAVE `let t = ticket` shouldn't work because you are assigning reference to object `ticket` to variable `t`, whereas `let t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ticket));` creates copy of object `ticket` and stores it in variable `t`.

Answer (score 0):

you also can do this

```
  replicateTicket(ticket:any){
          let a = Object.assign({}, ticket);
          a.name = ticket.name + ' (Replicated)';
          a.id = 0;
          this.ticketList.push(a);
        }
```